# How to calculate how much do I need to reach a goal?

Tags: google-sheets

I have to do 60 tasks in 30 days. That means I can do 2 tasks per day and at the end I will reach my goal.
Day 1 I do 2 tasks,
Day 2 I do 2 tasks,
Day 3 I do 1 task.

Then I want a formula to calculate how many tasks I am behind and display them in a cell.

I did this:
On cell X3:
=if(average(E4:V4)>D2, "Yes", "No") - to indicate if I am behind or not.
E4:V4 is the range where I enter the daily progress.
On cell Y3:
=if(X3="No",abs(average(E4:V4)-D2)*100,) - to calculate the percentage of how far I am behind.

I want this:
On cell Z3:
find the ammount that is missing in cell Y3 to get the result = 0.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(Y3=0,0,60-SUM(E4:V4))
```